# ASP JS - It is possible to pass a object created in a Classic ASP JS runat="server" to the client JS?

Tags: javascript, object, asp-classic

For example:

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
  var obj = {};
  obj.arg1 = 'we';
</script>
```

How can i get the obj object in my client JS to use it as a javascript object?

Comment: it's asp.net web forms, not asp classic, please change the tags

Comment: It is asp-classic :S. But i'll delete the question. Managed to pass the object using JSON (From a comment that no longer exist :S)

Comment: @GianniDiFalco: `runat="server"` is not asp-classic.

Comment: @Martha yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to loop through the object server side and build the object and set its values client side.

Comment: Managed to pass the object using JSON. Ur way sure works but it is a bit pain in the hand